# Javascript form post with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

**JS CODE:**

```
    function yetiskintext() {

    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").innerHTML="";
    var secenek=document.getElementById("yetiskinid").value;

    while (secenek>0){
    var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel.setAttribute("for","keke");
    newlabel.innerHTML = "Adı :";
    newlabel.className='selectTravelInputFieldsCarText';
    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").appendChild(newlabel);   

    var textBoxname = document.createElement('input');
    textBoxname.name = 'textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.id='textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.type = 'text';
    textBoxname.className='selectTravelInputFieldsCar';
    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").appendChild(textBoxname);

    var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel.setAttribute("for","keke");
    newlabel.innerHTML = "</br>";
    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").appendChild(newlabel);
```

**MAIN PHP PAGE:**

```
<div id="yetiskindiv"></div>
```

**FORM START:**

```
<form method="post" name="sigortayap"  action="sigorta-process.php" onsubmit="return dene()" >
```

**SIGORTA_PROCESS.PHP:**

```
<?php

    $yetiskinsayisi=htmlspecialchars($_POST["yetiskin"]);

    $cocuksayisi=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cocuk"]);
    $e=1;
     $a=htmlspecialchars($_POST["textyetiskinname".$e]);
    print $a; 

    echo $yetiskinsayisi;
    echo $cocuksayisi;


?>
```

I want to post my form. My form keeping js page i get form in `<div>`. How can I post this form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a submit button in your form to submit it:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
```

Here's what i've understood after looking at your code:

```
<form method="post" name="sigortayap"  action="sigorta-process.php" onsubmit="return dene()" >
```

when you say, `onsubmit="return dene()"` and `dene()` returns `false` then the form wont submit, so make sure that the function doesn't `false`.

If you want to do it via code:

```
<form id="yourform" method="post" name="sigortayap"  action="sigorta-process.php" onsubmit="return dene()" >
```

and in JS:

```
yourform.submit()
```

Comment: Or give that form an id (id="myform") and do in your script: 
> myform.submit();
then you can trigger it using JavaScript.